Should we highlight the invoice character of addresses per renaming the [address] tag?
The authors of BIP179 suggested that a Bitcoin "address" should rather be referred to as "Bitcoin Invoice Address". We still frequently get the question of how a shop owner could distinguish between payments of different customers buying products for the same price. It seems to me that referring to Bitcoin addresses as "Bitcoin Invoice Addresses" could help clarify why they should not be reused and how they apply to this issue.
Should we make address a synonym for a new tag bitcoin-invoice-address?

I don't think this is a good idea, as the term isn't common practice and using it this way would just confuse people.
It would be great if this name was the common way of referring to that concept, but I fear we're about 9 years too late to change that (this is also my criticism on the BIP itself).
